# Putting functions into a class

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

i'm trying to put multiple functions into a class. So that i will be able to push it out using an array. But i'm still not able to push the function into an array due to some errors. My program is to create an animated fish sprite in the canvas. To take it to the next step, i wanted to add more fishes into the canvas.

Comment: I can't get your example code to run--and the fish spritesheet is local to your file system.  But you should check out javascript "classes".  You define the properties and functions of a Fish in a class.  Then you can make as many "copies" (instances) of that class as you need.  You can store all those instances in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and simple example of a Fish "class".

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/jEznV/

The Fish class is used like a template to create as many copies of Fish as you need.

You define the Fish class and properties like this:

```
// A Fish Class

function Fish(x,y,speedX,speedY,img){
    this.image=img;
    this.xPos=x;
    this.yPos=y;
    this.speedX=speedX||1;
    this.speedY=speedY||1;
}
```

You define the functions (called methods) of the Fish class like this:

```
// change the x/y position of this fish

Fish.prototype.move=function(){
    this.xPos+=this.speedX;
    this.yPos+=this.speedY;
};

// draw this fish on the canvas

Fish.prototype.draw=function(){
    context.drawImage(this.image,this.xPos,this.yPos);
};
```

You can use the Fish class to create an actual fish object like this:

```
// create another fish using the Fish class

var anotherFish=new Fish(20,40,2,1,img);
```

And you can put all your fish in an array:

```
// an array holding several instances of Fish objects
var fishes=[];

// create 3 new copies (instances) of Fish at random positions/speeds

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var x=Math.random()*50-img.width;
    var y=i*img.height+25;
    var speedX=Math.random()*.25+.2;
    var speedY=.1;

    // create another fish using the Fish class
    var anotherFish=new Fish(x,y,speedX,speedY,img);

    // put this new fish into the fishes[] array
    fishes.push(anotherFish);

    // draw this new fish
    anotherFish.draw();

}
```

A tutorial of javascript classes is beyond the scope of a Stackoverflow answer, but this should get you started.

**[ Added code for an image preloader ]**

```
// image loader

var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];
imageURLs.push("FishStrip.png");
imageURLs.push("moreFish.png");
imageURLs.push("evenMoreFish.png");
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images

    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]
    // imgs[0] is FishStrip.png
    // imgs[1] is moreFish.png
    // imgs[2] is evenMoreFish.png

    // use the imgs[] to create your Fish instances now


}
```

Comment: I didn't have your spritesheet when I was working on your answer--so I used a fixed image.  But you can adapt the class to draw a multi-image sprite instead of a fixed image. ...It does work the same way ;-)

Comment: You move any part of your code that defines the Fish (those are called properties) and any part of your code that acts upon the Fish (those are called methods).  Then you have one animation loop that simply calls the Fish methods.  Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Z7cAB/

Comment: The start() function is called after the test image has been fully loaded (and you must give any images time to load before you send them to create a new Fish instances.  I don't have your code but it sounds like you're using more than 1 spritesheet.  If that's the case then you should use an image preloader that loads all your spritesheet images before you send them to create a new Fish.  I've added code for an image preloader to my answer.

Comment: Make sure that you use `this` when referring to instance properties.  For example in drawFish you must refer to this.animIndex (not just animIndex):     var frameIndex = animFrames[this.animIndex];  This will make the fish move its tail.  Check the rest of your code to be sure that inside the prototype functions you always refer to the instance properties using `this`.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Keep trying to check your work...I have confidence you will be able to get it from here!

Comment: I took another look.  Here's a corrected version where each Fish instance moves and animates fins.  You still have an intermittent problem when the fish hits the top and bottom of the canvas (this is related to your hit-testing, not the Fish class).  Also you are assigning the xPos & yPos in the class definition as canvas.width/2 and canvas.height/2.  This makes each fish start out at center-canvas.  Revised code:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tu6GM/